# Do we need to handle a `PoisonPill` case in `Akka` actors

Tags: scala, akka

It makes sense that we don't need to add a `case` for `PoisonPill` however, I didn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: You do not need to handle it, but you should avoid using `PoisonPill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle the PoisonPill (you can still handle Terminated to handle cleanup).

The PoisonPill is a way to let the actor finish handling any waiting messages before the PoisonPill was sent (vs. stop that only waits to the current message to be processed)